# Question about my code for Java Program that gets user input numbers and outputs the smallest and largest number

Tags: java, arrays, input

I am very new to programming, so please forgive me if this sounds ignorant. I started this program that calculated the smallest and largest number based on the preset numbers I put in my Array. After creating the program with it running, I realized I need user to input numbers.I am trying to acquire the same result. I added some code to allow me to get the user input for the numbers, however it doesn't work with the rest of the code. Is there a way to get it to recognize the user input with the calculations I already have, or do I need to start from scratch? I hope this makes sense.

```
package smallestlargestnumber;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author robert.huckestein
 */
public class SmallestLargestNumber {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        numbers = new int[9];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 different numbers.");
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            numbers[j] = sc.nextInt();
            int  largest = numbers[0];
            int  smallest = numbers[0];
            for(int i = 1; i<numbers.length; i++){
                if (numbers[i] > largest){
                largest = numbers[i];
                }
                else if(numbers[i] < smallest){
                    smallest = numbers[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("  The numbers given are" +Arrays.toString(numbers));
            System.out.println(" Largest number is " + largest);
            System.out.println(" Smallest number is " + smallest);
        }
    }
}
```

// Here is the compiled program of my code.

```
run:
Enter 10 different numbers.
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
    at smallestlargestnumber.SmallestLargestNumber.main(SmallestLargestNumber.java:31)
C:\Users\robert.huckestein\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 17 seconds)
```

Comment: What doesn’t work with your code?

Comment: @GokulNathKP  This is the compiled output       run:
Enter 10 different numbers.
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
 at smallestlargestnumber.SmallestLargestNumber.main(SmallestLargestNumber.java:31)
C:\Users\robert.huckestein\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 17 seconds)

Comment: 1. if you indent correctly your code you will find problems easier;
2. `int[] numbers = new int[10]`
3. declare the variables `largest` and `smallest` out of the for loop so they can be printed;
4. initialize `largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = new int[9];
```

This is wrong, you need to store 10 `int` so it must `new int[10]`

Change it and your code should work

Comment: It worked! Was it because the computer starts counting at 0?

Comment: @JakeHuckestein because of the array on every languages store from index 0, if you define `new int[9]`, it look like this `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` <= only 9 element allow inside. with `new int[10]` it will be `[0,1,...,9]` so it allow 10 element to store inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

As I see the problem was that you haven't read user input incompletely and have started to do the math.

I have updated the program for you. It's receiving all 10 numbers from a user and only then does the calculations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    {
        numbers = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 different numbers.");

        // read user's input for all 10 numbers
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            numbers[j] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // do the calculations
        int largest = numbers[0];
        int smallest = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > largest) {
                largest = numbers[i];
            } else if (numbers[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("  The numbers given are" + Arrays.toString(numbers));
        System.out.println(" Largest number is " + largest);
        System.out.println(" Smallest number is " + smallest);
    }
}
```